# How to move the input field of an Entry() in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to move the tkinter `Entry()` input field (the field inside the widget) to the first position (or a custom position)?

Example, I have this code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text='Example Entry:').grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(50, 5))
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=50, pady=(5, 50))

entry.bind('<Return>', lambda _: root.focus())
tk.mainloop()
```

After I run the code, I will open up a tk window with an entry.

Then, I input some characters into this entry ([example image #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Uzj.png)). After the input field runs out of space, it will hide the previous characters ([example image #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awDgc.png)). In the example image 2, the previous characters (`abcdef`) were hidden.

So my question is, how to move the field to the first position (or any custom position) whenever I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

I tried to use `entry.icursor(0)` but it only move the insertion cursor to the first position, not the whole field. I also did some Google searches but of course, no information. That's why I ended up in here.

**Expectation:**

- This is the result I got after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>: [example image #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ack2i.png)
- This is the result that I have expected after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>: [example image #4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrhiI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `xview` method to adjust the view of the data. The index you pass will be moved to the left edge of the widget, if possible. You should combine that with a call to `icursor` as well. And finally, I recommend returning the string "break" so that the default binding doesn't get processed. That really shouldn't matter, but it's a best practice if your intent is to change the default behavior.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack(fill="x", expand=True)

def go_to_beginning(event):
    entry.icursor(0)
    entry.xview(0)
    return "break"

entry.bind("<Return>", go_to_beginning)

tk.mainloop()
```